# open a url on click of ok button in android

Tags: android, button, click

I have to open a URL on Click of `OK` Button in a view. Can someone tell how to do this?

Comment: Use [HttpUrlConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html).

Comment: public void openWebURL( String inURL ) {
    Intent browse = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW , Uri.parse( inURL ) );

    startActivity( browse );
}

Comment: This will work perfectly dude.. so 1 up...

Comment: @tushar: have you tried it? i think it should work properly. do you get any error while running this code?

Comment: try this way http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html

Answer (score 293, accepted):

On `Button` click event write this:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"); // missing 'http://' will cause crashed
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

that open the your URL.

Comment: OR `startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"))`

Comment: @Chris-Jr you have missed the last parenthesis i.e. )

Comment: How is this different from opening a webview item?

Answer (score 9):

```
    Button imageLogo = (Button)findViewById(R.id.iv_logo);
    imageLogo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String url = "http://www.gobloggerslive.com";

            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the below method, which will take your target URL as the only input (Don't forget http://)

```
void GoToURL(String url){
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
    Intent intent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,uri);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String url = "https://www.murait.com/";
if (url.startsWith("https://") || url.startsWith("http://")) {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    startActivity(intent);
}else{
    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Invalid Url", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

You have to check that the URL is valid or not. If URL is invalid application may crash so that you have to check URL is valid or not by this method.

Answer (score 2):

Add this code to your OK button click listener.

```
startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com")))
```

Answer (score 1):

create an intent and set an action for it while passing the url to the intent

```
yourbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String theurl = "http://google.com";
                Uri urlstr = Uri.parse(theurl);
                Intent urlintent = new Intent();
                urlintent.setData(urlstr);
                urlintent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                startActivity(urlintent);
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for any Java or Kotlin code to make it a clickable link, now you just need to follow given below code. And you can also link text color change by using textColorLink.

```
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:autoLink="web"
android:textColorLink="@color/white"/>
```

Comment: Interesting, but it doesn't allow longClicks to override the autoLink.

Answer (score 1):

> The following code worked perfectly for me.

```
fun Context.goToUrl(url: String) {
if (url.startsWith("https://") || url.startsWith("http://")) {
    val uriUrl = Uri.parse(url)
    val launchBrowser = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl)
    startActivity(launchBrowser)

} else {
      Toast.makeText(this, "Invalid Url", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

}

call it in your actvity or fragment

```
requireContext().goToUrl("https://"+"something")
```

Comment: Note, I combined @Mahamud and Sojitra to arrive at this solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private fun goToUrl(url: String) {
        val uriUrl = Uri.parse(url)
        val launchBrowser = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl)
        startActivity(launchBrowser)
    }
```

Comment: Can you please give some explanation?