# how to perform Android Call php function from server(10.0.2.2)?

Tags: php, android

With reference to this link [open a url on click of ok button in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930228/open-a-url-on-click-of-ok-button-in-android)

i want to call php function in my xampp server by the builder button click "ok"

Answer (score 1):

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("10.0.2.2/sth.php?runFunction=true");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

PHP:

```
<?php 
if($_GET["runFunction"] == true){
    myFunction();
}

function myFunction(){
    ...
}
?>
```

Comment: Uri uri = Uri.parse("10.0.2.2/sth.php?runFunction=true");                 how to set username and password . my php function is located within a localhost server with some username and password

Comment: Then you `$_GET` the username and password variables and compare them against your database or whatever then you call the function.

Comment: can you give me an example code or something. i am an amateur

Comment: This is a good [Tutorial](http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/6.html).

Also don't forget to vote ;)