# Calling class or action in Android Button

Tags: java, android

I have a project to make two button. One button to open FileChooser, and another one to generate MD5 hash.

I have created the layout. I'm also already has the needed class, `FileChooser.java` and `md5.java`. But i'm still confused how to call them with `OnClickListener`.

```
findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        // Action

    }
});
```

I don't know what to write in that "Action" line to calling that both class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do one thing is that whatever method you required from md5.java or FileChooser.java , make that method static and then writing below code:

```
findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

      FileChooser.yourmethodname();

    }
});
```

Comment: Your example was great.
I'm lack knowledge about this "FileChooser.yourmethodname();"
and now i'll learn a bit. Thanks.

Comment: Please upvote it.If you found it as beneficial for you.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Usually you can employ a new action by starting a new intent

See this link for more information about chooser:
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-implement-a-share-intent--mobile-8433

See this link for example how intent is being deployed in a listener:
[open a url on click of ok button in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930228/open-a-url-on-click-of-ok-button-in-android)